# Why is initial stream being triggered again after combineLatest and merge in this example?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Look the excerpt below:

```js
  let requestStream = Rx.Observable
    .of(`${GITHUB_API}?since=${randomNumber()}`)
    .mergeMap(url => {
      console.log(`performing request to: ${url}`)
      return Rx.Observable.from(jQuery.getJSON(url))
    });

  let refreshStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(refreshButton, 'click')
    .startWith('click')
    .do(_ => users.empty())
    .combineLatest(requestStream, (_, users) => users.slice(randomNumber(users.length)));

  let randomUserStream = userRemovedStream
    .combineLatest(requestStream, (_, users) => users[randomNumber(users.length)]);

  requestStream
    .merge(refreshStream)
    .flatMap(users => users)
    .merge(randomUserStream)
    .filter(_ => users.children().length < MAX_SUGGESTIONS)
    .do(user => users.append(createItem(user)))
    .mergeMap(user => Rx.Observable.fromEvent($(`#close-${user.login}`), 'click'))
    .map(event => event.target.parentNode)
    .subscribe(user => {
      user.remove();
      userRemovedStream.next('');
    });
```

---

The `requestStream` returns an array with 100 users, however, I am consuming only three (`MAX_SUGGESTIONS`) of them at the time. `refreshStream` and `randomUserStream` exists in order to reuse the other 97 users from `requestStream`. The problem is, when I run the code above, I still see on console `performing request to: ...` three times.

*I've noticed that this happens after adding the `merge` methods in the last stream, however, I am not sure why this behaviour is happening.*

My understand is: when I `merge` `refreshStream` and `randomUserStream`, whenever a new item is emitted, a click on `refresh` button for the former and a click on `remove` button for the later, the previously emitted array on `requestStream` will be parsed and passed forward instead of the click itself. This should not re-trigger the `requestStream`.

Can someone help me understand why is this happening and how to deal with this situation? - so I can take the maximum out of the users already returned by the API during the first call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you have effectively three subscriptions to the `requestStream`. Your intuition in how the three interact is correct, however, because your `requestStream` Observable is cold it will create a new stream each time there is a subscription.

It isn't necessarily obvious because only one subscription is explicitly made, but each time you pass `requestStream` to `combineLatest` it will end up creating an new subscription which will in turn start a new stream, which in this case calls your underlying API.

If you don't want that to happen, I would suggest you use a multicasting operator like `publishLast`

So `requestStream` will become:

```
let requestStream = Rx.Observable
    .of(`${GITHUB_API}?since=${randomNumber()}`)
    .mergeMap(url => {
      console.log(`performing request to: ${url}`)
      return Rx.Observable.from(jQuery.getJSON(url))
    })
    .publishLast();
```

In this case `requestStream` is now actually a `ConnectableObservable` so you will need to also start it at some point, usually you would wait until all of your subscribers are hooked up.

```
/* Rest of you example */
.map(event => event.target.parentNode)
.subscribe(user => {
  user.remove();
  userRemovedStream.next('');
});

requestStream.connect();
```

Comment: That was a great explanation, thank you very very much! I'll look more into cold vs hot Observables and multicasting. So far it worked perfectly!